# Convert multi-line file to one liner and keep the \n

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that converts txt image with multi-lune to a single parameter which should be a single line because I need to pass it later as an argument to a different script.

the script removes the new lines "`\n`" and put space instead-but What I need is to leave the "`\n`" but still create a single line parameter.

original file (That is always changing and can have more/less lines), **images.txt**:

```
feeder-srv
 newTag: develop_eaf7128
input-registry-srv
 newTag: master_e16b788
shard-mongo-srv
 newTag: master_2d2262e
shard-es-srv
 newTag: master_66ac45e
```

Command to convert to one line parameter:

```
images_one_line=$(tr '\n' ' ' < images.txt)
```

parameter output is:

```
feeder-srv newTag: develop_eaf7128 input-registry-srv newTag: master_e16b788 shard-mongo-srv newTag: master_2d2262e shard-es-srv newTag: master_66ac45e
```

Which I later pass as argument to another script: `source wiki-update.sh "${images_one_line}"`

parameter output I need:

```
feeder-srv newTag: develop_eaf7128\n input-registry-srv newTag: master_e16b788\n shard-mongo-srv newTag: master_2d2262e\n shard-es-srv newTag: master_66ac45e\n
```

I need the "`\n`" because I then using curl to perform a REST-API request to edit a page and I need to keep a certain HTML format:

[image]

Comment: The literal characters backslash and n?

Comment: Or do just want to remove every other newline?

Comment: *"I need the "\n" because I then using curl to perform a REST-API request to edit a page and I need to keep a certain HTML format:"* - no you don't. You're trying to solve the *completely* wrong problem.

Comment: replace the new line with a special character instead of a space like '|', in the second script convert it back before you feed it to curl

Comment: `parameter output is:` Variable assignment does not output anything. Please post the _exact code_ you are using to get the output. `parameter output I need:` You want to replace newlines (one character) by two characters \ and `n`? Are you sure you are not asking XY question? `the script removes the new lines "\n" and put space instead-but` Please post the script sources.

Comment: `images_one_line=$(perl -0777 -pe 's/\n/\\n/g' images.txt)`

Comment: **1)** Why are you trying to cram the file contents on the command line, why does `wiki-update.sh` not accept a filename instead? **2)** `curl` accepts a filename for upload **3)** `curl` does not care about newlines in uploaded files. **4)** replacing newlines with a literal `\n` will not have the effect you want. **5)** HTML does not care about newlines unless you specifically use `<br>` or `<pre>` or CSS `white-space: pre;`. So whatever you're trying to do here, it almost certainly is the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check my awk-based approach below:

```
$ echo 'feeder-srv
newTag: develop_eaf7128
input-registry-srv
newTag: master_e16b788
shard-mongo-srv
newTag: master_2d2262e
shard-es-srv
newTag: master_66ac45e' | awk 'BEGIN{c=1;}
                               {
                                   if(c % 2 == 0){
                                       printf("%s\\n ", $0)
                                   }
                                   else{
                                       printf("%s ", $0)
                                   }
                                   c++;
                                }'

feeder-srv  newTag: develop_eaf7128\n input-registry-srv  newTag: master_e16b788\n shard-mongo-srv  newTag: master_2d2262e\n shard-es-srv  newTag: master_66ac45e\n
```